# What should I do when a user self-identifies as being under 13?

Tags: discussion, faq, policy, user-accounts

Stack Exchange Terms of Service have a minimum age of 13 to use the site.  This comes from US federal law COPPA - Children's Online Privacy Protection Act.

If a user self-identifies as under 13, what should I as a SE user do? What do mods do?

Comment: _Should_ implies moral obligation. While you _can_ report such a user to a moderator, the answer to your question is **nothing** because age discrimination is morally impermissible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ref. [Are moderators required to report users younger than 13?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236710/are-moderators-required-to-report-users-younger-than-13)

In a nutshell, as a SE user, you bring it to a moderator's attention, the moderator then brings it to [a community manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do)'s attention.